# Effective container that keeps order and is fast at deleting elements from any position

Tags: c++, optimization, containers

I am looking for a container in C++ that satisfies my following needs:

- I need to delete elements by index.
- Right after I delete one element, I will insert another on in the front (ALWAYS!!!!!)
- Besides that, there is not change in size.
- It NEEDS to be indexed.
- The values stored in the container are unique, as the index.
- One index should be assigned to one value. Unless i delete or add one values. Then the index should be adapted.

For another set of data, that is working kinda parallel to that container, I need one with these features and these additional:

- This one needs to work kinda in two directions: Since it stores a unique value, I need to be able to access the index through the actual value (which is 100% unique) very fast, since that will happen a lot of times.

I cannot grantee, that any of the value types support operators like `<`, `<=`, ... besides `==` and `!=`

If there are questions, go ahead an ask.
If something is unclear, I will further explain it.

EDIT:

Since I've been requested, here comes the actual problem behind that:

I am writing a library made out of an template container class, which is able to store a certain amount of objects. All these Objects are the same type. (Well, of course...) Another very important property of these objects must be, that they can be recreated by a unique index. this index could be also anything. An example in this case would be a two dimensional space, where you can create objects, that are on the plane and all there properties can be recreated by giving the object class the coordinates (as a single object in this case).
Now when the container reaches maximum capacity, it deletes the objects last used. My idea was here, that you give the container the unique index. If the desired object is still stored, the function return a pointer on the object and moves it inside the inner container to the front. If the desired object is NOT stored in the internal container, the last object in the internal container will be deleted and the new one will be generated and put to the front.

I need this, because I have a program which will easily use all my RAM and by far more. Well I could generated and destroy the object every time, but that just seems like a waste of computation power to me. So I came up with this container that only deletes the object, if it hasn't been used for quite a big time. Which is in my particularity case pretty useful (Path-finding on **HUGE** maps)

I hope that helps!

**EDIT2:**

Ok. I'm going to make this even more clear.

Let's start of with a simple data cache:

```
[0] d1  [1] d2  [2] d3  [3] d4
```

Now let's say I used d3.
The structure should now look like this:

```
[0] d3  [1] d1  [2] d2  [3] d4
```

Now I add a completely new element to the container (d5).

```
[0] d5  [1] d3  [2] d1  [3] d2
```

That is the idea behind. Now instead of `int`-values as index, I allow to have a custom index class, which is able to restore every single object, that might possibly deleted (That is not a problem. Just a requirement in order for my class to work).

Let's begin with the beginning statement. That looks like this for the first case:

```
[0] i1  [1] i2  [2] i3  [3] i4
[i1] 0  [i2] 1  [i3] 2  [i4] 3
```

The second example looks like this:

```
[0] i3  [1] i1  [2] i2  [3] i4
[i1] 1  [i2] 2  [i3] 0  [i4] 3
```

And finally the last state looks like this:

```
[0] i5  [1] i3  [2] i1  [3] i2
[i1] 2  [i2] 3  [i3] 1  [i5] 0
```

I hope that makes it more clear. For the second one more than one container might be possible.

Comment: Have you profiled something like `std::deque` to see if it is fast enough for what you need?

Comment: I have read about the properties and it did not seem a good choice. Like all the other popular containers too. I don't even mind using a container from boost.

Comment: More like you need std::map

Comment: http://devmentor.org/references/stl/stl.php std::list looks like what you are looking for

Comment: My biggest concern here is: "Are they fast at deleting and adding data?" I already said, I had a look at them and it did not really satisfy me. But I'll look again.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skip_list#Indexable_skiplist comes to mind. Don't know if there's any good C++ implementation you can use.

Comment: @WeeYou: Unfortunately `::std::list` isn't indexed.

Comment: There is not a data structure or combination of data structures that satisfies your requirements. In particular, being indexed (meaning O(1) time to access an arbitrary value by its ordinal position) and have O(1) deletion are not compatible. Perhaps going up a level and describing the problem you need to solve instead might be more fruitful.

Comment: By the way: Neither map, nor list are indexed or if, they do not adjust their index value, if I change elements. I also could use the container backwards, which should not be a problem. I am mentioning this, because i read it a couple times, that some containers are very effective in inserting elements to their back. Would `vector` be a good choice?

Comment: @YannickSchinko: `::std::vector` is O(n/2) for deletion of an arbitrary element.

Comment: map is index by key, why you think it's not indexed?

Comment: @bilz - Sure, it's indexed, but the indices won't change if you delete an element unless you do it manually...

Comment: @billz: I think by indexed that the OP means O(1) access through a numeric key that represents the ordinal position in a list.

Comment: Thank you so much for your edit. You want an LRU cache combined with a way to look up items quickly in the cache. You can get something fairly efficient here, but not O(1) efficiency for lookups or deletions. You'll likely have to combine a couple of different data structures to make this work.

Comment: @Omnifarious It knew from the beginning that I might have to use different structures for each of my two internal containers...

Comment: @YannickSchinko: I'm practically falling asleep at the keyboard or I'd try to come up with an answer.

Comment: I just had an idea: I could use list for the actual data. Since I can implement my indexed search pretty easy, picking the right element isn't too hard and it keeps everything nice and neat in order. And I could use vector for the ID data, because it is about as fast as list, when adding and deleting elements, but by far fast in finding elements. DO you think that will work?

Answer (score 3):

Sorry - I find your question a bit vague - but I'll state what I think your requirement must be then discuss the data structure needs...

So, we have indexed data like - something like this (where indexes are in brackets):

```
[0] a  [1] h  [2] b  [3] q
```

Your main operation is the delete/insert - say we did delete element 2 and insert value x, we'd have:

```
[0] x  [1] a  [2] h  [3] q
```

So, if we call the element index being deleted *n*, given what we've effectively done is move [0..n-1] along one position, then overwrite [0] with the extra value.

Discussion

If you do this operation with a vector, then the move operation can be arbitrarily large and relatively slow.  But if you use some other container such as an associative container (map, unordered map) you'd have to update the keys for all those "moved" elements anyway.  Other common containers don't provide O(log2N) or better indexing, so aren't promising, so let's stick with vector and see how to minimise the pain.  As well as the move being O(N), it involves shifting arbitrarily large objects: in the case when the objects are much larger than a pointer, you could have an array of points to objects and just move the array's pointers without moving the objects: that could be much faster (it's also useful for objects that don't like being moved, typical reason is the C++03 copy slowness for which C++11 introduced move operators).

I can't think of anything much better than this vector approach.

Returning to the vagueness of your question - if your confusing "index" with "key" and simply need a keyed container but don't need objects to shift their keys with each delete/insert operation, then a map or unordered map is a much better choice.

Comment: This seems to be a good approach. Would it make sense, to add elements to the back, instead of the front? And would the vector class not automatically adjust everything by itself?

Comment: Adding elements to the back isn't necessarily any better... main consequence would be if you happened to normally find the next element towards the back of the indices then there'd be a less object-moving involved, but I see no reason to assume that would happen.  Just to be clear - what would be massively faster is to insert the element where-ever the element you're removing had happened to be - then no copy/move of other elements is needed.  cont

Comment: ...The vector class does not automatically move elements: the vector represents an indexed area of contiguous storage... computer memory systems don't generally have a notion of whether specific memory is an array/vector is in use, and the program itself has to shift content to repack the array to keep it contiguous so that it can be indexed quickly using a baseAddress + sizeof(Element) * index approach.

Comment: Yeah. I figured. That's the reason, why I am going with `list` and `std::advance` though. But really thank you!!

Comment: Might work for you, but using `std::advance` to navigate to an arbitrary index *n* all the way from the first element will be very slow compared to direct indexing: possibly enough to stop your program working very well at all.

Answer (score 2):

Let's have a look at your requirements:

- Access by position
- Access by element
- Deletion at arbitrary position
- Unicity of elements

How to ?

- You need something with Random Access to support the "access by position", or at least close to Random Access O(log N) might be sufficient
- Given that elements may not support ordering, unicity would require the use of a hash-set

This can be easily achieved using Boost.MultiIndex I think. The [examples](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html) section already gives a MRU cache implementation and you are close enough. I would suggest combining:

- a [Random Access Index](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/multi_index/doc/reference/rnd_indices.html#synopsis): yielding Access and Deletion by position
- with a [Hashed Index](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/multi_index/doc/reference/hash_indices.html#synopsis): yielding Access by element and Unicity check

This means something like:

```
typedef multi_index_container<
  T,
  indexed_by<
    random_access<>,
    hashed_unique</*...*/>
  > 
> cache_type;
```

Note: that for a *Hashed Index* to work, you need both support for `==` (or a specialization of `std::equal<T>`) *and* a hash functor. The latter can be provided by the user at the point of declaration of the container if the type does not already support it.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. But I have a few questions about that: Is it fast/effective? If not, this is not an option! And will the "standard" index be automatically adapted? Means, if i delete one object, will the index hole be closed? Like 1 2 3 turns into 1 2?

Comment: @YannickSchinko: 1/ It's probably faster that the solution you proposed yourself, whether this is sufficient for your needs however is another thing altogether. Most notably: it's more space efficient than most "multiple-container" solutions 2/ Yes, all indexes are automatically kept in sync; this is actually one big selling point of this solution: no object is "partially" present.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using boost c++ libraries, take a look at Multi-index containers.

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html

Comment: I was thinking of using boost anyways. But I did not know, that something like that existed! thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Thank you everybody, but I found a very effective solution for this:

Since my problems requires the following data structure;

```
[0] d1  [1] d2  [2] d3  [3] d4
[0] i1  [1] i2  [2] i3  [3] i4
[i1] 0  [i2] 1  [i3] 2  [i4] 3
```

I decided, to use these Containers:

1. `list`
2. `list`
3. `map`

Through some research I found out about `std::advance` and `std::next`, which allow me to effectively access certain elements in the `list`. To update the map, I will just run a simple for loop, which should work quite efficient.

If you have better ideas, please post the here!

Thank you again!

Comment: `list` are probably the worst container you can use: not cache-friendly, bulky, etc... Note that `std::advance` is O(N) for list (ie, if you ask to advance by 18, it will advance 18 times). A `vector` of `unique_ptr` to objects will likely be more efficient.

Comment: Since i delete more, than I search, I really think list should be faster since deleting and adding is just O(1).

Comment: It depends on the number of items you have, and how expensive to move/copy they are. Beware that Big O complexity is only meaningful for *huge* volumes, for smaller volumes (~100/~1000 items) constant factors are more important.

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to point out the multi_index_container solution has the same inefficiency as using a vector for random access support: deletion will have a cost linear in the size of the data structure. Internally, the random_access index uses a data structure similar to a vector of pointers.

There aren't that many data structures that allow both random access AND deletion of any element at better-than-linear time. AFAIK std::deque has linear time deletion, unless the item is close to one of the ends of the sequence.

This leaves us with balanced binary trees (and variants, like skip lists). A self balancing binary tree can maintain the size of the subtree below any node at a fixed overhead, and with this "augmentation" implement random access in O(log n). Unfortunately, the default implementations of std::map generally don't have this feature. So using std::map and std::advance gives you linear time random-access. You can't implement efficient random-access "on top" of std::map as your user code is not aware of the tree manipulations done internally by std::map.

You could roll your own (AVL trees are relatively easy to implement). Can't think of any easier way unless you're willing to accept poor performance on either the random access lookup or the delete+insert operation. The "least bad" solution that doesn't involve trees is probably using std::deque

EDIT: The augmented tree data structures I've mentioned are known as http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic_tree.